# Use function in allowed values Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

In my Competition schema I need to add list of teams. I have defined a TeamSchema and also I have added some teams in the collection. Now I want to add a competitions and add list of teams to that competitions.

This is how my competition schema looks

```
Competitions = new Mongo.Collection("competitions");

var CompetitionsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
year: {
    type: String
},
division: {
    type : String,
    allowedValues: ['Elite', '1st','2nd','3rd','4th','Intro']
},
teams:{
    type : [TeamSchema],
    allowedValues: (function () {
        console.log(1); // this is logged
        return Teams.find().fetch().map(function (doc) {
            console.log(doc.name); // this is not even logged
            return doc.name;
        });
    }()) //here we wrap the function as expression and invoke it
}
```

});
Competitions.attachSchema(CompetitionsSchema);

Now when I am trying to insert using autoform like this

```
{{> quickForm collection="Competitions" id="insertTeamForm" type="insert"}}
```

I don't get list of teams to choose from. Am I doing something wrong here?

Team Schema

```
Teams = new Mongo.Collection("teams");

TeamSchema = new SimpleSchema({
name: {
    type: String
},
matches: {
    type: Number,
    defaultValue: 0
},
matchesWon: {
    type: Number,
    defaultValue: 0
},
matchesLost: {
    type: Number,
    defaultValue: 0
},
matchesTied: {
    type: Number,
    defaultValue: 0
},
points: {
    type: Number,
    decimal: true,
    defaultValue: 0
},
netRunRate: {
    type: Number,
    decimal: true,
    defaultValue: 0,
    min: -90,
    max: 90
},
pointsDeducted: {
    type: Number,
    optional: true
},
isOurTeam: {
    type: Boolean,
    defaultValue: false
}

});

Teams.attachSchema(TeamSchema);
```

Comment: `find()` returns cursor, and map requires array. You should use `find().fetch()`

Comment: still no luck with using fetch().

Comment: Also, your map doesn't change anything (you use it on array of objects nad you return array of objects), you should probably return some string, like `doc.teamName` or sth

Comment: Can I get a sample code?

Comment: `return Teams.find().fetch().map(function (doc) {
            return doc.teamName;
        });`

Comment: where teamName is a value from your db you want to sort with in SimpleSchema

Comment: how would that help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93983/discussion-between-chaudhry-mohsin-ali-and-sindis).

Comment: can you paste TeamSchema too?

Comment: just added teamSchema

Comment: Try what Sindis said. I modified the code for your schema. 
`return Teams.find().fetch().map(function (doc) { return doc.name; });`

Comment: check the updated schema. It is still not working.

Comment: What is the output when you log
`Teams.find().fetch().map(function (doc) { return doc.name; })`
to the console?

Comment: When I do it in the browsers console I get this ["Holmlia-CC"]. But when I try to console in allowedValue functions it doesn't console logs anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

allowedValues expects an array and you are passing a function to it. Doesn't matter if you are returning an array because the function is not invoked. You can use [Immediatelly invoked function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) like this

```js
var CompetitionsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
year: {
    type: String
},
division: {
  type : String,
  allowedValues: ['Elite', '1st','2nd','3rd','4th','Intro']
},
teams:{
    type : [TeamSchema],
    allowedValues: (function () {
        return Teams.find().fetch().map(function (doc) { return doc.name; });
    }()) //here we wrap the function as expression and invoke it
}
});
```

Comment: Will try this as soon as I reach home. Thanks mate.

Comment: It didn't get invoked.

Comment: I have updated my question and added a couple of comments for you to see.

Comment: I figured it out, Teams is not accessible there. I think I have to subscribe to it but not sure how to subscribe to a publication in collection.

Comment: If I add autopublish back again in my project it starts to work but as soon as I remove it stops. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not very good idea to use autopublish since it publishes all the data.

Comment: No no I am not using autopublish. I have removed the allowedValues attribute and populating a array of options on Template.MyTemplate.Helpers.